# Basic use of Linklabel tool in winforms gives Exception Handling Error

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, exception, linklabel

**SOLUTION: Add this code into the method:**

```
Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo() { FileName = url, UseShellExecute = true });
```

This simple code gives Exception Handling Error:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Label_LinkLabel_TextboxKONTROLLERI
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        LinkLabel dynamicLinkLabel = new LinkLabel();
        private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dynamicLinkLabel.BackColor = Color.Red;
            dynamicLinkLabel.ForeColor = Color.Blue;
            dynamicLinkLabel.Text = "I am a Dynamic LinkLabel";
            dynamicLinkLabel.TextAlign = (ContentAlignment)HorizontalAlignment.Center;
            dynamicLinkLabel.Text += " Appended text";
            dynamicLinkLabel.Name = "DynamicLinkLabel";
            dynamicLinkLabel.Font = new Font("Georgia", 16);
            Controls.Add(dynamicLinkLabel);
            dynamicLinkLabel.Name = "DynamicLinkLabel";
            string name = dynamicLinkLabel.Name;
            dynamicLinkLabel.Location = new Point(20, 150);
            dynamicLinkLabel.Height = 40;
            dynamicLinkLabel.Width = 300;
            dynamicLinkLabel.BackColor = Color.Red;
            dynamicLinkLabel.ForeColor = Color.Blue;
            dynamicLinkLabel.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;

            dynamicLinkLabel.ActiveLinkColor = Color.Orange;
            dynamicLinkLabel.VisitedLinkColor = Color.Green;
            dynamicLinkLabel.LinkColor = Color.RoyalBlue;
            dynamicLinkLabel.DisabledLinkColor = Color.Gray;

            dynamicLinkLabel.LinkArea = new LinkArea(0, 22);
            dynamicLinkLabel.Links.Add(24, 9, "http://www.c-sharpcorner.com");
            dynamicLinkLabel.LinkClicked += new LinkLabelLinkClickedEventHandler(LinkedLabelClicked);
        }
        private void LinkedLabelClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
        {
            dynamicLinkLabel.LinkVisited = true;
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("http://www.c-sharpcorner.com");
        }
    }
}
```

The code above has been taken from this website: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/linklabel-in-C-Sharp/

Here is the exception picture:

[image]

Here is the CS8604 Warning: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/nullable-warnings?

[image]

I did not understand what causes this. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: For .NET 5+ you must use ProcessStartInfo so you can set its UseShellExecute property to true.

Comment: @HansPassant how do I do that?

Comment: Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo() { FileName = url, UseShellExecute = true }); adding this code into the method solves it.